# Creating an excel chart with multiple survey results

Tags: graph, charts, excel, pie-chart, vba

I recently did a survey, which had upto 10 questions. Now I need to create a graph out of the values, but am stuck. The data is below:

```
Customer ID Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5                      Q6  Q7  Q8  Q9  Q10
1797493605  Yes Yes Yes Yes Compare totals          Yes Yes Yes Yes None of the above
1797155787  Yes Yes Yes Yes Compare prices          Yes Yes No  Yes None of the above
1797116920  Yes Yes Yes Yes Compare totals          No  No  Yes No  Catalogues
1797105343  Yes Yes Yes Yes Compare prices          Yes Yes Yes Yes None of the above
1797076252  Yes Yes Yes Yes Same places             Yes Yes Yes No  None of the above
1797015113  No  No  No  No  Everything online       No  No  No  No  None of the above
1796959310  Yes Yes Yes Yes Compare prices          Yes No  No  Yes None of the above
1796950913  Yes Yes Yes Yes Compare prices          Yes Yes Yes Yes Catalogues
1796931846  Yes Yes No  Yes Compare prices          Yes No  Yes Yes Email/SMS
```

I tried using the Excel normal functionality, but it just does not provide the correct graph.

would like to get a Bar Graph, with each question having 2 bars - for each answer. With the X-axis having the questions and the Y-axis the number of people who answered?

Can the data values then should be the actual Yes, No, ? If so, how?

Comment: You want "yes" and "no" to be data points on your chart?

Comment: Yes No and also the other data. Can that be possible?

Comment: are you trying to get the counts/sum of those responses?  Or actually show the responses?  Because I can't even picture what that latter would look like.  I.e. how would it differ from the general grid presentation?

Comment: Can I get a Bar Graph, with each question having 2 bars - for each answer, with the X-axis having the questions and the Y-axis the number of people who answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't care about customer ID.

What you're trying to get is a grid of this format, where row 1 is your heading (I'm fabricating the numbers here):

```
|     |  A   |  B  |  C   |
===========================
|  1  |  Q   |  #Y |  #N  |
|  2  |  Q1  |  6  |  1   |
|  3  |  Q2  |  5  |  2   |
|  4  |  Q3  |  2  |  5   |
```

And in order to populate cell `B2` (which holds the # of `YES` answers to `Q1`, you would use a formula like this one against your grid:

```
=SUMIF($B$2:$B$10,"YES")
```

That `SUMIF()` formula counts the number of "YES" responses in the Q1 column of your grid.

(I'm assuming that in YOUR grid "Q1" responses are contained in Cells `B2` thru `B10`.)

Build that table, and then you'll be able to highlight that table, click into the Excel Chart Wizard, and manipulate it into the bar chart you're seeking.

If that's not your answer, you will need to be more specific about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Marc, I also have some multiple answer questions, which have more than just YES NO... how do I put those in a graph?

Comment: @gagneet, Whatever the answer is that you want to count, replace the `"YES"` in the formula listed. I.e. if you want to count how many users answered with a response of "cheeseburger", use `=SUMIF($B$2:$B$10,"cheeseburger")`

Comment: thanks Marc. I have some questions with different choices. Can I build them into the same Chart? or do I need to create different charts for each? Like for Q5, I have 3 choices which are different from the rest of the answers...

Comment: @gagneet, in short, yes.  But you'll have to decide what looks best for your purposes. I'm afraid I cannot design this for you, and the answer to your question seems to be a moving target. Please apply the techniques I've provided as you see fit to get the desired results. And if my solution has answered the original question asked, please accept it at your convenience.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand Your problem correctly, you want to create a specific bar graph with the data format you showed.

Well as Marc pointed out, to create the graph that you want in native excel, you must rearrange your data.

However, if you want to keep your data in the same format, I propose you write Javascript to draw this chart in excel. Here is a working code I have written for you :

https://www.funfun.io/1/edit/5a463a3fb848f771fbcdef58

What I do in this example, at first, is to get the data with a json file :

`{ "data": "=A1:J9" }`

After having acces to it, I use javascript to select the data I need and select a library to create my bar chart (here I used chart.js, it is pretty easy to use):

```
  var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    title: {
        display: true, 
       text: "Excel chart with multiple survey results" 
      },
    barValueSpacing: 20,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: 10
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

If this is the chart you are after, you can directly load my code with your spreadsheet by pasting the URL in the [Funfun add-in](https://www.funfun.io/1/msaddin). Here is how it looks like :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWjZc.png]

You can of course modify the code in the online editor or in the embedded editor in Excel. You can add other labels different than `Yes` or `No`, you can have a third bar per question named `Compare price`.

In theory, you could code whatever you want, including creating complex charts by using powerful libraries like chart.js and plotly.js.

I hope I answered your problem, if not don't hesitate to comment below.

**Disclosure : I’m a developer of Funfun.**

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a table. Customer ID as column headers, Q1-Q10 as row headers. The transposed version of what you've presented.

Comment: I would like to get a Bar Graph, with each question having 2 bars - for each answer.       With the X-axis having the questions and the Y-axis the number of people who answered?

Comment: So Customer ID is irrelevant?  Is that what you're saying?

Comment: @gagneet, your original question asks for "Cust ID" on the X-axis.  Now you're saying that's not what you want.  Right?

Comment: I wanted it to be that way, but seems that would not be a chart which can be created. Hence the change in the description. I have changed the question accordingly.